# Can not pickle function in zeppelin's python interpreter

Tags: python, pickle, apache-zeppelin

I can run the following code correctly in python shell, but could not run it in zeppelin python interpreter.  Here's the implementation of zeppelin's python interpreter. https://github.com/zjffdu/zeppelin/blob/master/spark/src/main/resources/python/zeppelin_pyspark.py

Could anyone help me to understand why the pickle doesn't work in zeppelin python interpreter ? Thanks

Code

```
def f():
    "hello"

import pickle
pickle.dumps(f)
```

Output

```
Fail to execute line 5: pickle.dumps(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/dp/hmchg5dd3vbcvds26q91spdw0000gp/T/zeppelin_pyspark-5559547270503920588.py", line 338, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x104317840>: attribute lookup f on __main__ failed
```

Comment: BTW why would you need to pickle a function?

Comment: This is just for my project's feature. I'd like pass python function to jvm side and call jvm function and then pass this function to python process again.

Comment: This seems like an issue you should file with Zeppelin's github page.

Comment: yes, I created that, but I suspect it is to due to pickle's internal mechanism. so ask question here.